# Compiler produce slower program although I gave information

Tags: c, x86, avx, icc, xeon-phi

In my knowledge, giving information(like using `restrict`, `static` on function, `__builtin_expect()`, etc) to compiler makes program better or equal. However, this works opposite to what was expected.

This is a function that changes the order of data storage in a matrix(packing method for matrix multiplication). Size of `src` matrix is `m` * `n`, and size of `dst` matrix is `MAX_M` * `MAX_N`. Case 2) line is disabled yet.

```c
// pack.c

#define MAX_M 5000
#define MAX_N 5000
#define EPC 8  // number of Elements Per Cache line
               // also AVX-512 SIMD register can hold up to 8 double-precision floating points.

void pack(int m, int n, const double *restrict src, double *restrict dst) {
    int upper_n = (n + EPC - 1) / EPC;
    int remainder_n = n % EPC;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < upper_n; ++j) {
            int len = j < upper_n - 1 || remainder_n == 0 ? EPC : remainder_n; // case 1)
            // int len = EPC;                                                  // case 2)
            for (int k = 0; k < len; ++k) {
                dst[i * EPC + j * EPC * MAX_M + k] = src[i * n + j * EPC + k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used the code below to measure performance of `pack` function. This code runs the `pack(5000, 5000, A, B)` 50 times and measures the average execution time. `A` and `B` are aligned with 64 bytes, and both sizes are 5000 * 5000.

```c
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define MAX_M 5000
#define MAX_N 5000

#define ITERATION 50

void pack(int m, int n, const double *restrict src, double *restrict dst);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int m = 5000;
    int n = 5000;

    double *A;
    double *B;

    posix_memalign((void **)&A, 64, sizeof(double) * m * n);
    posix_memalign((void **)&B, 64, sizeof(double) * MAX_M * MAX_N);

    for (int i = 0; i < m * n; ++i) A[i] = i;

    double total_duration = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATION; ++i) {
        double start_time = omp_get_wtime();
        pack(m, n, A, B);
        double end_time = omp_get_wtime();
        double duration = end_time - start_time;

        total_duration += duration;
    }
    printf("avg duration: %.8lf s\n", total_duration / ITERATION);

    free(A);
    free(B);

    return 0;
}
```

It only calls `pack` with `n=5000`. It means `remaninder_n` in `pack` is always 0 and `len` is always 8. So I used case 2) instead of case 1) in `pack` function.

**Then weird thing happens. Performance becomes worse. case 2) is slower than case 1).** I gave information(`len` is always 8) to compiler, but compiler produced slow code.

```
avg duration: 0.05746786 s    <- case 1)
avg duration: 0.06110375 s    <- case 2)
```

**Is it possible that giving information to compiler makes program slower? Or is it just an issue with the compiler?**

Target machine is Intel Xeon Phi 7250(Intel Knight Landing). Compile command is `icc -o perf_test main.c pack.c -qopenmp -march=knl -O3`. Assembly of `pack` function is like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/foYY76o9E) except that mine uses `movslq` but the link uses `movsxd`.

---

I tested by modifying some codes. So I could figure out that 'case 1) is faster than case 2)' is a special case.

Case 2) becomes faster than case 1) if I

- change compiler to `gcc` from `icc`
- move `pack` function to main.c file
- remove `restrict` keyword from `pack` function
- remove `-march=knl` flag

Case 1) becomes slow as case 2) if I

- change case 1)'s `remainder_n` to any integer literal

  ```c
  int len = j < upper_n - 1 || remainder_n == 0 ? EPC : 0;

  or

  int len = j < upper_n - 1 || remainder_n == 0 ? EPC : EPC;
  ```

In other words, case 2) is slower than case 1) if none of the above conditions are used. I don't know why compiler create slow program when these conditions are given.

Comment: `movslq` is the AT&T mnemonic for `movsxd` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx:movsxd), sign-extension from 32 to 64-bit.  (Typical if the compiler can't prove an `int` is non-negative when using it to index an array.)

Comment: This is just a manual transpose?  Normally matrix libraries have optimized code for this, probably including the case where the storage geometry doesn't match the matrix, i.e. there's padding at the end of each row or not, if that's why you're calling it `pack`.   Also, optimized matmul functions can normally handle the input matrices being transposed or not, doing it on the fly or auto-vectorizing in a way that suits the layout, so you normally don't want a separate pass over the whole data just transposing not doing any math work the whole time.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?  Why ICC makes different asm, or why the asm difference creates a performance difference on KNL?  If the latter, you should show the asm difference in the question.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for commenting. My question is nearly latter, "why the asm difference creates a performance difference on KNL?" and "why does ICC produce slow code even I gave more information(`len` is always 8)?" In my knowledge, the more information programmer gives, the more optimization opportunity comes for compiler. It seems nonsensical that providing more information would result in worse performance in the current situation.

Comment: I'm studying how to create fast matrix multiplication routine. The `pack` codes are only for this purpose. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: I would first of all replace all `int` (all which are used for indexing) by `long` (or `ptrdiff_t`), this will prevent a lot of sign-extension code and can help the compiler to optimize the code better. I would also recommend to compare with other compilers, e.g. clang is typically quite good in optimizing shuffles.

Comment: Note: `for (int k = 0; k < len; ++k) dst[i * EPC + j * EPC * MAX_M + k] = src[i * n + j * EPC + k];` replaceable with speedier `memcpy(&dst[i * EPC + j * EPC * MAX_M],  &src[i * n + j * EPC], sizeof dst[0] * len)`.  Consider adding some test code to verify not writing out of array bounds.  If pointers are not `restrict`, use `memmove()`.

Comment: *Is it possible that giving information to compiler makes program slower?* - It shouldn't, but in practice compilers are imperfect.  They're not "smart", they're just complex pieces of machinery that spit out machine code.  Often they rely on heuristics, not an exact performance model of the target machine.  So yeah, it's hopefully rare that this happens, but totally believable.  Sometimes just a quirk of code alignment will bite you, other times a compiler just makes worse code.  Keep in mind this is ICC, which Intel is replacing with LLVM-based ICX, probably for reasons like this.